# How to set a value for drop down list in Excel using Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, watir

I'm new to Ruby/Watir and I'm currently working on a script that grabs values from a web page and places them in an existing excel spreadsheet.  The problem I'm encountering is that there are drop down lists in the spreadsheet and my code is writing the value in the cell instead of selecting from the drop down.  This is a problem because it causes an error in the spreadsheet calculation. Can anyone offer some advice or solution please?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://mywebaddress'

excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('G:\LH Rating Script\HB3 DRC sheet.xml')
excel.Visible = true
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('MAIN')

worksheet.Cells(48, 5).Value = "#{browser.select_list(:id =>'phContent_WPU_QuestControl44H_WPU_Control44H').getSelectedItems[0]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems my problem wasn't what I thought it was.  The cell with the drop down I was trying to set a value for had a alert messaging saying that cell was formatted as text or proceeded by an apostrophe. So If I change my code to place an apostrophe in front of the value then it will go into the spreadsheet correctly.